# How to resolve a null reference exception in a null check statement?

Tags: c#, properties, nullreferenceexception, null-check

I've added a null property check to a boolean method, to prevent returning true, if any string fields are empty in a SelectedCustomer property.

The problem is my bool method gets called from the constructor, before I've input any data into the SelectedCustomer model. This then causes a Null reference exception.

I can see from the breakpoint I set on the statement that, "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}" is the error. The selectedCustomer property isn't initialized until I select a customer from a data grid.

My question is, how can I perform the null check in this manner without causing a NRE?

This is the CanModifyCustomer boolean method where I perform the null check:

```
private bool CanModifyCustomer(object obj)
{

    if (SelectedCustomer.FirstName != null && SelectedCustomer.LastName != null && SelectedCustomer != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;            
}
```

It is passed as a param in my buttons command:

```
public MainViewModel(ICustomerDataService customerDataService) 
{
    this._customerDataService = customerDataService;
    QueryDataFromPersistence();

    UpdateCommand = new CustomCommand((c) => UpdateCustomerAsync(c).FireAndLogErrors(), CanModifyCustomer);

}
```

And this is the SelectedCustomer property that the null check is preformed on:

```
 private CustomerModel selectedCustomer;
    public CustomerModel SelectedCustomer
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedCustomer;
        }
        set
        {
            selectedCustomer = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedCustomer");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the selectedCustomer property isn't initialized, then what do you think might be causing a **null** reference exception in your code?

Comment: Because the property wasn't initialized yet. It is initialized when I input values. But if I initialize it with default values my null check will never evaluate to true during program run. Or am I missing something silly here?

Comment: What else could you check for null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use null conditional operator. (C#6)

```
if (SelectedCustomer?.FirstName != null && SelectedCustomer.LastName != null)
{
    return true;
}
```

Or you should put `SelectedCustomer != null` at first. because the condition is evaluated from left to right. so if first one is false because of using `&&` operator it will not continue to check the other parts and the condition becomes false.

```
if (SelectedCustomer != null && SelectedCustomer.FirstName != null && SelectedCustomer.LastName != null)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ok that resolved the issue, thanks. I just had to check if the property itself was null also in summary not just the fields.